# Creating a dropdown using database in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Hi I am trying to create a dropdown using a CI forms. I have a table reseller and in that i have a field called Key. Now I have another table Users where i store user's information. I want to create a new user and in that user creation form i have a drop down field called Key where i want to fetch the key of all the resellers. So that i can identify which user is mapped to which reseller using that key.

For Controller I have done this :

```
$data = $this->user_m->array_from_post(array('sip_id','sip_pass','name','key','email', 'password','phone','status','created','balance'));


                $this->load->model('reseller_m');

                $this->data['resellers'] = $this->reseller_m->get('key');

                $data['password'] = $this->user_m->hash($data['password']);




                $key=$this->user_m->save($data, $id);
                redirect('admin/user');


                }

                $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/add';
                $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
```

The View is

```
<tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <?php if(count($resellers)): foreach($resellers as $reseller) ?>
    <td><?php echo form_dropdown('key', set_value('key', $user->key));?></td>
</tr>
```

But i dont get anything on screen. So How to create this drop-down?

Comment: is the `:` after `if(count($resellers))` a typo or intentional?

Comment: @Blip actually i copied it from an example : <tr>
  <td>Status</td>
  <td><?php echo form_dropdown('status', array('Active' => 'active', 'Inactive' => 'inactive', 'Delete' => 'delete'), $this->input->post('status') ? $this->input->post('status') : $user->status ); ?></td> 
 </tr>

Comment: in your last comment, there is a **ternary** if else operator `(condition)?true : false` which you are not using in your method that you have posted. So remove the `:` and check out.

Comment: i did that as well but not working i also did this   <tr>
  <td>Key</td>
  <?php if(count($resellers)): foreach($resellers as $reseller) ?>
  <td><?php echo form_dropdown($reseller = array($reseller->id,$reseller->key));?></td>
 </tr>

Comment: i have updated the question code please check @jalpa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try it like this:

```
    <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <?php if(count($resellers) > 0) {
                  foreach($resellers as $reseller) { ?>
                  <td>
                      <?php echo form_dropdown('key', set_value('key', $user->key));?>
                  </td>
                 <?php } 
                 } ?>
    </tr>
```

Is this variable right: `$user->key`? I think you need to use: `$reseller->key`.

Comment: thanks for the answer  in my crontroller i do this :  $this->data['resellers'] = $this->reseller_m->get(); but then also i get an error undefined value Reseller

Comment: @Rajan Can you please tell me what value store in this array `$resellers ? i mean in this $this->data['resellers'] = $this->reseller_m->get();`

Comment: i should have been blank coz i am trying to fetch the reseller values in user controller

Comment: how do i pass that key of reseller from my controller to view?

Comment: any idea where i am wrong in my controller i did this :$this->data['resellers'] = $this->reseller_m->get()

Comment: Find this line `$this->data['resellers'] = $this->reseller_m->get('key'); and replace with this  $data['resellers'] = $this->reseller_m->get('key');`  ?

Comment: @ jalpa see i have a user controller and reseller controller so will this work in user controller : $data['resellers'] = $this->reseller_m->get('key');

Comment: @ jalpa can you please help me here

Comment: @Rajan sorry, but i didn't get you on last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89447/discussion-between-rajan-and-jalpa).

Comment: @ jalpa see i have a user controller where i create user and fetch them so will this line of code work $key=$this->user_m->save($data, $id);  because as you see in my code $data[] also has the post values of users